# On the meaning of boundedness for $\mathbb R^k$-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis

On Rudin's book, the author said "a mapping $f$ of a set $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$ is said to be bounded if there is a real number $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in E$."

So $f(x)$ should be an element of $\mathbb{R}^k$. What's the absolute value of $f(x)$? For example, if $f(x) = (1,2,3)$, $|f(x)|=\sqrt{1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2}$?

Maybe [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) can be an answer for my question.

Thank you!

Comment: Whichever norm, they are all equivalent (in finite dimensional spaces). Mostly, the Euclidean norm is used, also fairly often maximum norm and sum norm. The sharpest bound depends on the chosen norm, but not the existence of a bound.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any continuity or compactness in this question.

Comment: @ChrisEagle This is a first definition in the subchapter: contunity and compactness in Rudin.

Comment: Often $\|x\|$ is used, but also $|x|$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$. Without any other specification, they usually mean the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Modified the title (which was indeed misleading).